# pycrypto is down? how to install pycrypto?

Tags: python, pycrypto

The following is what happens:

```
$ sudo easy_install pycrypto
Searching for pycrypto
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pycrypto/
Reading http://pycrypto.sourceforge.net
Reading http://www.pycrypto.org/
Download error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://www.amk.ca/python/code/crypto
Reading http://www.pycrypto.org/
Download error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://www.pycrypto.org/
Download error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
Best match: pycrypto 2.3
Downloading http://www.pycrypto.org/files/pycrypto-2.3.tar.gz
error: Download error for http://www.pycrypto.org/files/pycrypto-2.3.tar.gz: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

and firefox is unable to connect to pycrypto.org -- no connection can be established. So if pycrypto is down, how do I install pycrypto?

EDIT: I *can* however ping the site, so I'm not sure how that works:

```
$ ping pycrypto.org
PING pycrypto.org (76.10.145.51) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 76-10-145-51.dsl.ncf.ca (76.10.145.51): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=159 ms
64 bytes from 76-10-145-51.dsl.ncf.ca (76.10.145.51): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=161 ms
64 bytes from 76-10-145-51.dsl.ncf.ca (76.10.145.51): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=160 ms
^C
--- pycrypto.org ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 159.418/160.471/161.223/0.767 ms
```

Comment: Both pycrypto.org and dlitz.net (where you can also get the source code) seem to be unresponsive right now. I do know the sites were up since I installed pycrypto yesterday, so this might just be downtime. Also, you might be able to ping them because the server they're hosted on is still up, just that their site itself is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCrypto releases are now uploaded to PyPI, so easy_install should no longer rely on the availability of the dlitz.net webserver.

Answer (score 2):

Softpedia also has a copy of the file:

http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Development/Libraries/PyCrypto.shtml

Once you have the archive, I believe you should be able to install it with

```
$ sudo easy_install pycrypto-2.3.tar.gz
```

(I used `pip` in my case so the line above isn't confirmed.)

Answer (score 0):

Google finds a copy of the file in [Fedora's code repository](http://cvs.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/python-crypto/pycrypto-2.3.tar.gz/c28500ebcf3a9a9b89ec6086fe397c70/).